# Closed ball in the intrinsic surface metric: is it compact?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a **regular and complete** surface and let $d$ be the intrinsic metric of $S$ given by $d(p,q) = \inf \ell(\alpha_{p,q}) $, the infimum taken over the length of all piecewise differentiable curves joining $p$ to $q$. This is a metric in the sense of metric spaces and we may consider the set: 
$B_d[p,\epsilon] = \{x\in S: d(p,x)\leq \epsilon\}$, the closed ball around $p$ of radius $\epsilon$.

Is it true that $B_d[p,\epsilon]$ is a compact set of $S$? I think it is closed since $d$ is a metric, but I'm not sure if it will be compact. Any hints, please? I am stuck

Comment: What if you take $S$ to be the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, $p=(1,0)$ and $\epsilon=2$?

Comment: It's part of the Hopf-Rinow theorem that geodesic completeness of a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ is equivalent to all the closed and bounded subsets of $M$ being compact.